# Python - cannot import name 'ohlc'

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/icoprimers/pyttrex/blob/master/pyttrex/average_true_range.py) code from a github repo which I already cloned. I already have plotly installed but I keep getting the error:

> "cannot import name ohlc"

Is there a way to solve it? Did anyone else get a similar error?

Answer (score 1):

---

I can't replicate - it works for me.

Here are possible issues:

- Did you clone/download the entire pyttrex project?
- Is your `average_true_range.py` file still in the same folder (`pyttrex/pytrrex`) as your `__init__.py` file?
- Is the first defined function in `__init__.py` still:

  `def ohlc(*args, **kwargs):`

Or have you removed or altered the name of the function?

- Have you edited any of the files to create or import a different function, variable, etc. named `ohlc` that could cause a name conflict with the import statement in `average_true_range.py`?

Comment: I tried again and now i get the error "no module named pyttrex", altough i cloned the repository, also, if i do "pip install pyttrex" i get nothing

Comment: Hmmm, did you clone by using:     'git clone https://github.com/icoprimers/pyttrex.git'  in a command line on your computer?  That got it all in for me ("That's what she said.")

Comment: Yeah, tried your command and it says 'destination path 'pyttrex' already exists and it's not empty'

Comment: so you've already got it cloned. what IDE are you using?  Are you able to confirm that '__init__.py' and 'average_true_range.py' are still in the same folder?

Comment: Yep, i'm using IDLE and init.py is in the same folder of average

Comment: The 'no module named pyttrex' error makes it sound like your pyttrex module is not in the system PATH variable.  Is it installed in the folder where your other python packages are installed?  If not, we may need to add it to PATH.

Comment: Here is how i installed it: 'pip install git+https://github.com/icoprimers/pyttrex'

Comment: Yeah, i can see ohlc defined

Comment: It could be a PATH issue - at least the most recent error ('no module named pyttrex') sound like that.  Can you tell if you've installed pyttrex into one of the folders in your computer's PATH variable?  (If it's in a folder where other python packages you're able to import are located, then it probably is fine)

Comment: I think i understood where the error could be. I have both python 2.7 and 3.6 installed, could this be the problem?

Comment: Definitely - you might have installed pyttrex in a python3 location and are using python2 to try to run the program (or vice versa).  , You could try running the pyttrex program from both Python2 and Python3 to see if at least one of them works.

Comment: Nope, it's not running from both. Did i do everything right? I download and extracted the folder on my desktop, then installed every module and did 'pip install git+github.com/icoprimers/pyttrex', could i be missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just cloned from git and it seemed to work.  You might do a pip uninstall ('pip uninstall pyttrex') to see if you can get rid of that version, and then run the 'git clone https://github.com/icoprimers/pyttrex.git' command from your command to just clone it.  That's all I did.  Then I opened a new project in my IDE (pycharm - I clicked 'open new project' then navigated to the pyttrex folder that I just cloned and selected that folder. Then opened 'average_true_range.py' from the folder tree on the side and ran it. (I had some TA-Lib issues, but the pyttrex imports worked fine.)

Comment: Tried to uninstall pyttrex but it didn't even find it, so the error is that i did not install it properly, don't know how

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't successfully installed `pyttrex`.

Comment: Well, i tried using pip but it seems not to find any module